# django 'null value in column'

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I try to save user's birth date, but get "null value in column "dob" violates not-null constraint" error.

models.py:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)

  nickname = models.CharField(max_length=32)
  dob = models.DateField(null=False)
  sex = models.BooleanField(null=False)
```

Here i try to generate random users:

```
def create_random_users(userCount=1000):
  random.seed()

  for i in range(0, userCount):
    sex = random.randint(0, 1)
    name = random.choice(names[sex])

    email = "{0}{1}@mail.com".format(name, i)
    user = soc_models.User.objects.create_user(email, email, password='password')
    user.save()

    userProfile = soc_models.Profile.objects.create()
    userProfile.user = user
    _year = random.randrange(1962, 1995)
    _month = random.randrange(1, 12)
    _day = random.randrange(1, calendar.monthrange(_year, _month)[1])
    userProfile.dob = datetime.datetime(_year, _month, _day)

    userProfile.sex = random.randrange(0, 1)
    userProfile.city = random.randrange(4000000)
    userProfile.country = random.randrange(230)
    userProfile.save()
```

Thank you.

Comment: your date format is not correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.create) method is documented as "a convenience method for creating an object and saving it all in one step".  So when the following statement in your sample data creation script runs:

```
userProfile = soc_models.Profile.objects.create()
```

It attempts to save an empty `Profile` object to the database.  Since you haven't set the `dob` attribute at this point, you trigger the `NOT NULL` constraint.

Two ways to avoid this are:

1. create the object via the constructor so that it isn't immediately saved to the database.
2. provide values for all the fields via keyword arguments to `create`.

Comment: Thanks. It explains everything.

Answer (score 1):

When using `create`, you must pass all required values to it, if you want to call `save()` later, use model constructor instead, i.e.:

```
userProfile = soc_models.Profile()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether it fixes your error or not, but regarding to docs, `DateField` should be used for storing `datetime.date` instance, and `DateTimeField` to store `datetime.datetime`.

P.S. Really, it looks like you trying to "migrate" DB scheme (to change already created columns). Django doesn't support such feature, but you can use external applications, like [South](http://south.aeracode.org/).

Comment: I completely dropped old schema and changed format to DateTimeField, but still have the error.